# How do I complete the Mister Freeze and Penguin mission?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I was playing Batman: Arkham City, and I went to rescue GCPD undercover cops in the mister freeze and penguin mission.  After I freed three in the torture chamber I went to the armoury and eliminated the thugs. Then I went to the penguin where he was shooting at me with his ice gun.

Batman said he should go to Mister Freeze's armor and get the gadget. I went back to the armoury where his suit was. Online guides say a cutscene will appear here, but nothing happens. What should I do? Is there any way to play the game from the beginning of this mission?
Does anyone have a save game and a gfwl account i could use?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether or not Arremer's answer is THE answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to **talk to the Mr.Freeze** again before taking the suit.

If that's not it you can try and actually push the button on the suit container.

You can also check the rest of the video in case you forgot something else.